# Angular :Error: Module build failed (from ./node_modules/@angular-devkit/build-angular/src/babel/webpack-loader.js)

Tags: angular, ng-bootstrap

Browser application bundle generation complete.

5 unchanged chunks

Build at: 2022-01-19T10:26:27.862Z - Hash: ed3af335fca1055f - Time: 3028ms

./node_modules/@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap/fesm2015/ng-bootstrap.mjs - Error: Module build failed (from ./node_modules/@angular-devkit/build-angular/src/babel/webpack-loader.js):
TypeError: Cannot create property 'message' on string 'C:\Users\win7\Firstapp\node_modules@ng-bootstrap\ng-bootstrap\fesm2015\ng-bootstrap.mjs: visitor.visitCastExpr is not a function
2504 | }
2505 | NgbDatepickerNavigationSelect.ɵfac = i0.ɵɵngDeclareFactory({ minVersion: "12.0.0", version: "13.0.3", ngImport: i0, type: NgbDatepickerNavigationSelect, deps: [{ token: NgbDatepickerI18n }, { token: i0.Renderer2 }], target: i0.ɵɵFactoryTarget.Component });

> 2506 | NgbDatepickerNavigationSelect.ɵcmp = i0.ɵɵngDeclareComponent({ minVersion: "12.0.0", version: "13.0.3", type: NgbDatepickerNavigationSelect, selector: "ngb-datepicker-navigation-select", inputs: { date: "date", disabled: "disabled", months: "months", years: "years" }, outputs: { select: "select" }, viewQueries: [{ propertyName: "monthSelect", first: true, predicate: ["month"], descendants: true, read: ElementRef, static: true }, { propertyName: "yearSelect", first: true, predicate: ["year"], descendants: true, read: ElementRef, static: true }], ngImport: i0, template: enter code he2507 |     <select #month
> 2508 |       [disabled]="disabled"
> 2509 |       class="custom-select"'
> at run (C:\Users\win7\Firstapp\node_modules@babel\core\lib\transformation\index.js:37:15)
> at run.next ()
> at Function.transform (C:\Users\win7\Firstapp\node_modules@babel\core\lib\transform.js:25:41)
> at transform.next ()
> at step (C:\Users\win7\Firstapp\node_modules\gensync\index.js:261:32)
> at C:\Users\win7\Firstapp\node_modules\gensync\index.js:273:13
> at async.call.result.err.err (C:\Users\win7\Firstapp\node_modules\gensync\index.js:223:11)
> at C:\Users\win7\Firstapp\node_modules\gensync\index.js:37:40
> re
> |                                      ^

× Failed to compile.

Answer (score 0):

i think that you have to be sure of the version of **ng-select** that you had installed on your angular project.
for each version of angular you should install a specific version of ng-select

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).